# Этимология слова "мужлан"

Tags: этимология

Мужланом называют неотесанного, грубого, необразованного человека. Но мне вот интересно, откуда взялось это слово? Корень у него, вроде, русский - как я понимаю, от слова "мужик", а произносится на французский манер.
Получается, что это какое-то синтетическое слово? Или русский корень тут ни при чем?

Comment: Я могла бы употребить слово мужлан в отношении мужчины немолодого, который не обязательно, как тут пишут, неотёсанный или грубый, но чем-то непривлекательный, утративший молодость и сексуальность, но продолжающий себя вести так, будто лучше молодых красавчиков, вызывая часто отвращение у девушек, не понимая своей омерзительности и вызывая брезгливость.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, пункт 2 по [этой ссылке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F). У Вас это слово не первый раз вызывает трудности.

Answer (score 3):

Мужлан - простонародное слово, отмечено в Словаре 1847. В нем два суффикса : **-л-** и **-ан**. Ср. : горлопан, болван, чурбан. В.В.Виноградов пишет :

> **экспрессивный суффикс -л-** этимологически выделяется и в слове мужлан. Слово мужлан является презрительным, бранным обозначением грубого, невоспитанного человека, свойственным фамильярному стилю устной речи.

Comment: Насчёт "простонародного" Вы "погорячились". Слово самое, что ни на есть, "высокородное". Слово "мужик" в те времена означало не просто "мужчину", а "мужчину низкого сословия" (как правило - крестьянина). Ну, а "мужлан" у нашего "офранцузившегося" дворянства - "характеристика" дворянина, ведущего себя "по-мужицки" (ну, там, по русски на приёмах разговаривает, духами не пользуется, на "политес" плюёт...)

Comment: Позвольте не согласиться.  
>П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. Книга первая (1871-1874)  
― Девица чай его пить зовет, а он нос на сторону… **Мужлан ты сиволапый!** . Другой бы за честь поставил, а ты, глядь-ка поди!  
(Нацкорпус)

Все ранние примеры из русской литературы абсолютно в том же роде : мужлан - грубая деревенщина и тп. Ближе к 20 веку словцо перекочевало в среду интеллигенции - мужланами стали называть просто грубых и невоспитанных субъектов.  
>**Мужлан, мужланюга, мужло** м. пск. грубый, неотесанный мужик, неуклюжий парень.  
(Словарь Даля)

Comment: Ну, что "*мужлан - грубая деревенщина*" я согласен ("мужик" - "крестьянин", "мужлан" - "ведущий себя по-крестьянски")... Возражение вызывает "родовитость" этого слова. Вы указали "простонародное", но "в народе" не могло сформироваться слово "как мужик" с негативным оттенком.  
Мужик себя "неправильным" не считает. И слово "*мужлан, мужланюга*" воспримет, скорее, как комплимент ("сильный", "ответственный" и т.п.)...  
Купец в начале 19в. еще гордится своим "простонародным" происхождением (некоторые - даже "бравируют"). Для него "подобный мужику" тоже - не оскорбление.

Comment: А,вот, дворянство воспринимает намёк на "худородность" как вызов. И любое сопоставление с крестьянином будет восприниматься им как оскорбительное.

Comment: Помета "простонародное" стоит в академическом Словаре 1847. В Словаре РЯ 11-17 вв читаем :  
>**Мужланъ**... как прозвище : *Михалко Мужланъ*. (из источника 1624 г.)

Также не забываем объяснение Даля, см. выше.

Answer (score 1):

Слово действительно выглядит "офранцуженным". Как, впрочем, и те, кто его придумал (русское дворянство XIX века). Однако, этимология вполне русская. Суффикс -ан- подчёркивает признак "муж", суффикс -л- указывает на характерное поведение.
Т.е. "мужлан" - человек (дворянин), ведущий себя подчёркнуто "по мужицки" (как простолюдин).